# How to limit the number of lines in grid css?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to make 2 columns with 5 elements each. I currently have 6 elements, which means that 5 of them should be in the first column, and the sixth should be put on the 2nd column.
Should be:
[image]

but now:

[image]

```
html:
 <ul class="footer-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Maps</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Style</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Exebitions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
</ul>
css:
    .footer-menu {
     display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
      grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post you HTML, we cant help you if we dont see what youve done

Comment: They are downvoting because you question format is not good, see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at this property

```
grid-auto-flow: column
```

[See CanIUse usage of this property](https://caniuse.com/?search=grid-auto-flow)

[See w3c documentation about this property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-auto-flow.asp)